# Attempt to gitolite mirror says "you should pull first"

Tags: git, gitolite

Some of the repositories we mirror using `gitolite` are now erroring with:

```
% gitolite mirror push mirror-host repo/path
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/feature/FOO-XXX-bar (you should pull first)
...
 ! [remote rejected] feature/FOO-XXX-bar (non-fast-forward)
```

The user invoking `gitolite` is in the `@admins` group, which has the `RW+` permission for *everything*. Why would not the tool rewind?

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: What part of the message don't you understand?  Your local copy is out of date ( there are newer changes on the server since you last pulled ), so you need to pull first to get those changes before pushing.

Comment: These aren't _working trees_, that can be pull-ed. These are repo-mirrors, which are _fetch_-ed. Are you a `gitolite`-user, psusi? If not, please, refrain from participating further. Thank you.

Comment: Pull and push do not require a working tree.  Most often you push to and pull from a bare repo.  The server is telling you that your local repo and its repo have diverged.

Comment: Yes, I know that repos have diverged. My question is, _what to do_. Simply trying to `git pull` on the replica responds: `fatal: /usr/bin/git-pull cannot be used without a working tree.`

Comment: Ahh, yes, doing a merge requires a working tree, so if you are trying to push from one bare repo to another, you will need to either check out a working tree there, or if there is already another server, then you will need to pull and do the merge locally and push that to the first server, which can then push to the second.

Comment: I think, I found a better way (below).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22481/discussion-between-psusi-and-mikhail-t).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this out. For whatever reason, the *repository*/config-files on the replicas contained the following clause:

```
[receive]
        denyNonFastforwards = true
```

Once I commented that out, I was able to run `mirror push`:

```
 ...
 + 5d7eb28...f0deef7 feature/FOO-XXXX-bar -> feaure/FOO-XXXX-bar (forced update)
 ...
```

Comment: By doing that you just destroyed/overwrote whatever new changes were on the server ( that's what forced update means ).

Comment: The server is a standby, which is not supposed to have ever been committed (pushed) to directly anyway. But, I think, the problem arose from invalid characters used in some `refs` -- the only replicas, that rejected the non-fast-forward sync were the ones, which _also_ rejected invalid characters earlier. I've expanded the list of valid characters first and now replicas are also just that -- replicas.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with that; if the replica had simply rejected a push before, and now is configured to accept it, then it would have worked without needing the forced update.  The fact that it needed a forced update indicates that someone *did* push a divergent branch to it, and you tossed out that divergent branch and replaced it with yours.  Unless perhaps you rebased or otherwise rewrote your history and pushed that to your first server as a forced update, and only the second server was configured to refuse forced updates.